# Simpler proof of the Lax-Milgram Theorem if A is symmetric

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, dual-spaces, linear-pde, riesz-representation-theorem

In ["Numerical Approximation of Partial Differential Equations"](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-540-85268-1.pdf) the authors Alfio Quarteroni and Alberto Valli state in remark 5.1.1, that the Riesz Representation Theorem suffices to prove the following Theorem, if $A$ is additionally assumed to by symmetric.

**Theorem. (Lax-Milgram)**
Let $(V, (\cdot, \cdot), \| \cdot \|)$ be a (real) Hilbert space and $A \colon V \to V^*$ a linear, strongly positive, bounded operator, that is there exist $\mu, \beta > 0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    \langle A u, u \rangle \ge \mu \| u \|^2
    \quad \text{and} \quad
    \langle A u, v \rangle \le \beta \| u \| \| v \|
    \quad \forall u,v \in V,
\end{equation*}
where $\langle f, v \rangle_{V^* \times V} =: f(v)$ is the dual pairing of $V^*$ and $V$, for $v \in V$ and $f \in V^*$.
Then $A$ is bijective.

**Here's is my attempt at a proof only using Riesz.**
As $A$ is symmetric, bounded and strongly positive, $(u, v)_A := \langle A u, v\rangle$ is a inner product on $V$.
As $(V, (\cdot, \cdot)_A)$ is a Hilbert space (due to the boundedness and the strong positivity, the induced norms are equivalent to each other), by the Riesz Representation Theorem, there exists a isometric isomorphism $\iota \colon V^* \to V$ such that $\langle f, v \rangle = ( \iota(f), v )_A = \langle A \iota(f), v \rangle$ for all $f \in V^*$ and all $v \in V$.
This implies $\langle f - A \iota(f), v \rangle = 0$ for all $f \in V^*$ and all $v \in V$ and hence $f = A\iota f$ for all $f \in V^*$ and hence $A \iota =$id, so $A$ is invertible with $A^{-1} = \iota$.

**Is my proof correct?**

Comment: How do you know that $(V,(\cdot,\cdot)_A)$ is complete?

Comment: Yes, this proof is correct.

Comment: @daw I'll accept it if you write this as an answer. I wouldn't like to delete this question since it might be useful for people searching for this proof.